# Titanium Alloy, Require Controller

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a project build in titanium SDK 3.02 using the Alloy framework.
Its a tabbed application, and I want to change the view of tab2 from a button inside tab1

tab1.xml

```
...
    <Button id="button" onClick="setup">
...
```

tab1.js

```
function setup(){
    //this doesn't work
    var view = Alloy.createController('tab2');
    view.changeBackground('blue');
    $.tabGroup.setActiveTab(1);
}
```

tab2.xml

```
...
    <View id="view" backgroundColor="red">
...
```

tab2.js

```
...
    exports.changeBackground = function(color){
        $.view.backgroundColor = color;
        //this runs eg
        Ti.API.info('function running');
    }
```

I understand why this wont work. I am creating a new instance of the controller which is never added to a view. But i want to access the existing controller.
I have tried

```
var view = require('tab2');
view.changeBackground('blue');
```

But this gives me a 'module not found error'. 
I hope this makes sense

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it

Setting the function in tab2 as an Alloy.Global did the trick.

tab1.xml

```
...
    <Button id="button" onClick="setup">
...
```

tab1.js

```
function setup(){
    var changeBackgroundColor = Alloy.Globals.changeBackgroundColor;
    changeBackgroundColor('blue');
    $.tabGroup.setActiveTab(1);
}
```

tab2.xml

```
...
    var changeBackground = function(color){
        $.view.backgroundColor = color;
    }
    Alloy.Global.changeBackGroundColor = changeBackground;
...
```

Comment: doesnt work for me, I was trying to hide/disable a button from son view to parent view

Answer (score 0):

That's one way.
The other (which IMHO is better because you avoid Global) is simpler.
You can access the tab just by doing:

```
function setup(){
    //This DOES work.
    // Just keep in mind that you must use the tab index corresponding to your tab.
    // Also, If your view actually uses a window and the tab is on your TabGroup view,
    // you should do $.tabGroup.tabs[1].window.
    var view = $.tabGroup.tabs[1]; 
    view.changeBackground('blue');
    $.tabGroup.setActiveTab(1);
}
```